# Kendo UI Mobile textbox focus below keypad

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

Is there a way in the Kendo UI Mobile to have a textbox on focus show above the keyboard. Or auto move the view up so the textbox is visible above they keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

```
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize"/>
```

This should go in your config.xml file.